# Agregar palabra "de" a fecha en momentjs

Tags: momentjs

¿Cómo puedo agregar la palabra "de" en la fecha usando momentjs?

Ejemplo: `4 de Mayo de XXXX`

El día, mes y año dan lo mismo, lo importante es agregar la palabra "de" en la fecha.

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer, seria obtener por separado la fecha, día, mes y año en a cada variable, luego interpolacion, es una manera rápida que veo, y sencilla.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Si usas moment.js, es muy sencillo formatear la fecha en una línea, lo que propones es más complejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [], por ejemplo:

```
moment().format('[de] YYYY');     // de 2018
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto y en una sola linea de código, gracias.

Answer (score 7):

Cargando la [locale](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) para Español es así de simple:

```js
let now= moment();
console.log(now.format('LL'));
console.log(now.format('LLLL'));
//Personalizado, hay que poner entre corchetes el texto que no sea la fecha en sí misma
console.log(now.format('[Hoy es] dddd, DD [de] MMMM [de] YYYY [y son las] HH:mm'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/locale/es.js"></script>
```

Comment: buena respuesta pablo, guardando.

Answer (score 5):

momentjs soporta múltiples formatos según la cultura que quieras.
https://momentjs.com/

```
moment().format('LL');   // 11 de abril de 2018
```

Sólo tienes que descargar la librería con todas las culturas y usar el código que te pongo arriba.

https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js

Answer (score 5):

Aquí tienes la forma como lo haría yo, solo debes cambiar el formato de idioma, as nada.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", prueba);

function prueba(){

   var anio, mes, dia;
   anio = moment().format("YYYY");
   mes = moment().format("MMMM");
   dia = moment().format("dddd");
   alert(dia + " de " + mes + " de " + anio);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="prueba">Presionar</button>
```

Comment: Si no cargar la locale, los nombres salen en inglés ;)

Comment: No puse lo de `locale`, y lo especifique :D

Comment: De esta misma forma lo hice, pero sale mas optimo ocupar [] en la cadena de moment format, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: de nada, de paso, aprendí yo algo con tu concejo.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales a mi me sale `wenesday de April del 2018 `

Answer (score 3):

Una variacion de la respuesta de [Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155004/28035), puedes tener varios idiomas y tu decidas cual visualizar, por defecto moment.js carga el idioma ingles:

```js
moment.locale('en');
let en= moment();
console.log(en.format('LL'));
console.log(en.format('LLLL'));


moment.locale('es');

let es= moment();
console.info(es.format('LL'));
console.info(es.format('LLLL'));

moment.locale('fr');

let fr= moment();
console.warn(fr.format('LL'));
console.warn(fr.format('LLLL'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/locale/es.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
```

Ahora con Javascript nativo seria de la siguiente forma:

```js
const dias_semana = ["domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miercoles", "jueves", "sabado"];

const meses = ["enero", "febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre"];


let mi_fecha = new Date();

console.log(`Hoy es ${dias_semana[mi_fecha.getDay()]},${mi_fecha.getDate()} de ${meses[mi_fecha.getMonth()]} del ${mi_fecha.getFullYear()}`)
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, haré una corrección con respecto a al mes.