# Cómo formatear una fecha en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo formatear un objeto fecha de JavaScript para imprimirlo como 12-Septiembre-2018 o 12 de Septiembre del 2018, etc?

Como ejemplo podríamos pasarle de parámetro la fecha actual.

Comment: que has intentado, que has hecho? muestra un poco de código para identificar correctamente el problema que tienes.

Comment: Hola @TheVicious no he hecho nada, no es un problema de corregir o ampliar código

Comment: con el comando [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) puedes generar la fecha y de alli puedes manipularla como quieras; por defecto tomara la fecha [dependiendo de la localidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: @JackNavaRow conozco el comando, pero como la formateo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Puedes utilizar el método toLocateDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

```js
    let f = new Date();
    let opciones = {
      weekday: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    };

    let fecha = f.toLocaleDateString('es-MX', opciones);

    console.log(fecha); // miércoles, 12 de septiembre de 2018
```

O podrías crear tu propia función de formato utilizando [métodos del objeto fecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date):

```js
    let f = new Date();
    let fecha = `${f.getDate()}/${f.getMonth() + 1}/${f.getFullYear()}`;
    console.log(fecha); // 12/9/2018
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías utilizar [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com), seteas el lenguaje con `moment.locale('es')` y luego lo parseas utilizando el método [`.format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

```js
// seteo el lenguaje
moment.locale('es');

// formato con guiones
var date = moment().format('D-MMMM-YYYY');
console.log(date);

// escapando "de" y "del"
var date2 = moment().format('D [de] MMMM [del] YYYY');
console.log(date2);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: y se pueden hacer otras cosas en moment.js dejo esta [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155000/agregar-palabra-de-a-fecha-en-momentjs/155014#155014) para complementarla

Answer (score 0):

...para continuar la consulta, si tomas la fecha desde un
;

let inputFecha = document.querySelector('#inputFecha');

esta me muestra la fecha pero en formato americano o sea al revés, como debería hacer para cambiarla a formato latinoamericano para que quede mas legible? Muchas Gracias.

el resultado de como me muestra la fecha es: 2022-04-26

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/332571)

Comment: Puedes editar y añadir esa duda también o mejor incluso creas otra pregunta aparte