# Convertir un valor obtenido en Horas:Minutos:Segundo a Horas:Minutos

Tags: javascript

Hola actualmente tengo un valor obtenido que me da en Horas:Minutos:Segundos lo que quiero es Convertirlo en Horas:Minutos

```js
//Valor Obtenido por el id
 var HoraActuales = $('input:text[id=COMD_FECHA]').val();
 console.log(HoraActuales)//=> Sale un ejemplo 10:40:9 
 //Lo que quiero es hacer que sea 10:40
```

Comment: Porque no simplemente cortas la cadena?

Comment: o pujedes declarar un new Date con esos parametros y obtener toda la info como tu quieras

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155014/28035

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Intenta tomar el valor del input así:
var HoraActuales = $('input#COMD_FECHA').val();

//Lo que tienes que hacer es tomar los primeros caracteres que quieres mostrar
//Usa la función substring()
console.log(HoraActuales.substring(0,5));
```

Comment: Lo malo es que me sale este error , debe ser por la version del jquery que tengo instaldo en el visual studio de mi proyecto:                             
script.js?v=1.1.2:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js?v=1.1.2:31)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, intenta tomar el input como te muestro ahi.

Comment: Nada me sale saliendo el mismo error que : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined at HTMLDocument.

Comment: Si puedes colocar tu html para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya listo esta abajo

Answer (score 2):

Es facil si trabajas solo con html css y js puedes agregar moment.js [descargar](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js) si esta usando nodejs bien puedes instalarlo con `npm install moment --save   # npm` para mayor informacion sobre moment.js ver la [documentacion](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
(function()
{
  // instantiate a moment object
  var NowMoment = moment().format('h:mm'); // October 5th 2018, 2:41:19 am
  
  // instantiate a JavaScript Date object
  var NowDate = new Date();
  
  // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;
  
  // display value of Date object in #displayJsDate div
  var eDisplayDate = document.getElementById('displayJsDate');
  eDisplayDate.innerHTML = NowDate;
})();
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<h2>JavaScript Date</h2>
<!-- container for JavaScript Date output -->
<div id="displayJsDate"></div>

<h2>Moment Date</h2>
<!-- container for Moment.js output -->
<label>Formato:'h:mm'</label>
<div id="displayMoment"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Fecha de Atención</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="COMD_FECHA_ATENCION" name="COMD_FECHA_ATENCION" value="@Model.COMD_FECHA_ATENCION.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="COMD_FECHA">Hora de Atención</label>
                                <input type="hidden" id="txtHoraEAtencion" value="@Model.COMD_FECHA.ToString("HH:mm")">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="COMD_FECHA" name="COMD_FECHA" value="@Model.COMD_FECHA" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto , aqui te dejo el codigo , asumo la variable que recibes es string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Intentalo</button>

<p id="resuesta"></p>
<input type="text"  id="COMD_FECHA" name="COMD_FECHA" value='10:40:9' />

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var temp=$('#COMD_FECHA').val().toString().substr(0,5)
    document.getElementById("resuesta").innerHTML = temp;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```